# How to create a "clip-path" circle on IE and Firefox?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have this snippet for cicrle-masking.
It works on Chrome.

But how to run it on Firefox and IE ?
Please no radius-borde solution...

```css
.circle {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 100px 100px);
  clip-path: circle(100px at 100px 100px)
}
```

```html
<img src="http://cp91279.biography.com/Leonardo-da-Vinci_A-Divine-Mind_HD_768x432-16x9.jpg" width="1024" height="768" alt="" class="circle"/>
```

.circle {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 10%);
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 10%);
}

Answer (score 4):

Well IE doesn't support the CSS clip-path at all and Firefox only supports the url method so that solution is pretty much a dead end - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

However you could use inline SVG to clip an image as it has great browser support - http://caniuse.com/#search=inline%20svg

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve" width="200px">
  <defs>
    <!--defines the shape to use for clipping-->
    <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="clip">
    <!--creates the clipping mask from the shape-->
    <use xlink:href="#circle" overflow="visible"></use>
  </clipPath>
  <!--group containing the image with clipping applied-->
  <g clip-path="url(#clip)">
    <image overflow="visible" width="768" height="432" xlink:href="http://cp91279.biography.com/Leonardo-da-Vinci_A-Divine-Mind_HD_768x432-16x9.jpg"></image>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Working example - http://codepen.io/taneleero/pen/BNZjdj

Comment: could you add a shrinking animation to the clipped SVG when hovering?